# The bit representation of a variable in C++

Tags: c++

I hope someone can help me out with this problem.
I have this C++ program that will be able to print the bit representation of some variables.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>

//macro for extracting the ith bit from a given char.
#define EXTRACTBIT(ith,ch)(std::cout<<(ch & (1 << ith) ? 1 : 0))

/*printlnbits is a function which prints the bit representation of a variable (least 
significant bit must be shown on the right) followed by its size (in bits).*/

template <typename T> void printlnbits(T v)
{                                         
   const int v_size = sizeof(v) * 8;
   int j=0;
   char* ch = reinterpret_cast<char*>(&v);

   for (int n = v_size - 1; n >= 0; --n)
   {
       j++;
       EXTRACTBIT(n, *ch);
       if (j == 8)
       {
          std::cout << " ";
          j = 0;
       }
   }
   std::cout << "\t" << v_size << std::endl;
}
struct foo {
   int a = 2;
   char b = -1;
   unsigned long long int x = 1LLU << 63;
};

int main()
{
   const char a = 'a';
   const int b = -1L;
   const unsigned c = 1<<31;
   const float d = -0.0f;
   const long long unsigned e = 1LLU<<40;
   const foo f;
   printlnbits(a);
   printlnbits(b);
   printlnbits(c);
   printlnbits(d); 
   printlnbits(e);
   printlnbits(f); 
   return 0;
}
```

Code output:
[image: code output]

The problem is with `d`, `e` and `f` variables. The bit representation of them is incorrect. I don't know what's wrong with my code. I'm a bit new in C++. Can anyone help????

Comment: If you are new to C++, why not learn the language by writing a useful application or two, rather than messing around with this stuff?

Comment: What is "incorrect" for you? What did you expect and what did you get? The standard does not impose a bit representation for variables, so you can get different outputs from different implementations.

Comment: Use `std::bitset` instead.

Comment: Inside C++ we have a religion. Our teachings go against macros(`*`). Come join us and meet eternal bliss. (`*`) except for the cases where it's properly justified.

Comment: `std::bitset` is fairly useful to represent certain bit's structures of variables of known size.

Comment: please don't post images of text. Copy paste the text instead.

Comment: All bit representations look valid, probably are correct for your machine.  What did you expect to get?

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but in computing the size of an object, don't multiply by 8. Multiply by `CHAR_BIT`, which is a macro that expands to the number of bits in a `char`. That value is usually 8, but there are systems where it is not. And, of course, writing `CHAR_BIT` makes it clearer what the purpose of that number is.

Comment: @KamilCuk do you actually think that on the OP's platform the bit representation of `1LLU<<40` is 64 zeroes?

Answer (score 2):

You never increment pointer `ch` to the byte being inspected. So you inspect the same byte over and over again. At the same time `n` which is a global bit index is used instead of `j`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <climits>

template <typename T> void
printlnbits(T const & v)
{                                   
   auto const p_bytes_begin{reinterpret_cast<unsigned char const *>(::std::addressof(v))};
   auto const p_bytes_end{p_bytes_begin + sizeof(v)};
   auto p_byte{p_bytes_begin};
   auto bit_index_in_byte{0};
   for(;;)
   {
       ::std::cout << (((*p_byte) bitand (1 << bit_index_in_byte)) ? '1' : '0');
       ++bit_index_in_byte;
       if(CHAR_BIT == bit_index_in_byte)
       {
          ::std::cout << " ";
          bit_index_in_byte = 0;
          ++p_byte;
          if(p_bytes_end == p_byte)
          {
              break; // for(;;)
          }
       }
   }
   ::std::cout << "    " << (sizeof(v) * CHAR_BIT) << " bits" << ::std::endl;
}
```

[online compiler](https://wandbox.org/permlink/n2uSszcsLK1lt9WN)

```
10000110     8 bits
11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111     32 bits
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000001     32 bits
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000001     32 bits
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 10000000 00000000 00000000     64 bits
01000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 11111111 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000001     128 bits
```

Comment: This shows that the provided output did not come from the code provided (unless the system in question has 32-bit characters).

Comment: Thanks for your help your code helped me a lot to understand the whole idea of bit representation. Thank you again :) @VTT

Answer (score 1):

I do not see increment of 'ch' here

```
  for (int n = v_size - 1; n >= 0; --n)
   {
       j++;
       EXTRACTBIT(n, *ch);
       if (j == 8)
       {
          std::cout << " ";
          j = 0;
       }
   }
```

You just see first byte.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
template<typename T>
void print(T v) {
    int s = sizeof(T) * 8;
    for (int i = s - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if ((i+1) % 8 == 0) std::cout << ' ';
        std::cout << ((v & 1 << i)? 1 : 0);
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

For float type and others, you can simply use:

```
std::cout << std::bitset<int(sizeof(float) *8 )>(d) << '\n';
```